# Bash scripting Show arguments and create a counter for them

Tags: bash

So I have to create a script that does something like this:

```
./scriptname.sh 1 2 4 carrot apple
1. 1
2. 2
3. 4
4. carrot
5. apple
```

Show them in a counter no matter how many arguments I give it.

I've tried doing this, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
k=0;
while [$k -lt $#]
do
    k=$((k+1))
done
echo "$k"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop never touches the arguments passed, it simply uses the variable `$#` which is the total number of arguments - never the arguments themselves.

If I were given this assignment, I would do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get no of args
noArgs=$#
# Save arguments in array
myArr=("$@")

# Loop the array
for ((i=0; i<$noArgs; i++)); do
    echo $((i+1)). ${myArr[$i]}
done

exit 0
```

A couple of examples:

```
./printArgs.sh foo bar baz
1. foo
2. bar
3. baz

./printArgs.sh 1 2 napalm death
1. 1
2. 2
3. napalm
4. death

./printArgs.sh seasons in the abyss
1. seasons
2. in
3. the
4. abyss
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
k=0;
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; 
do
    let k=k+1
    echo "$k $1"
    shift
done
exit 0
```

Comment: what does -gt 0 mean?

Comment: -gt 0 : "greater than zero" (since shift removes the inputs one after one)